# Doesn't WMAppManifest.xml get overwritten?

Tags: windows-phone-7

An update to my WP7 app was just released. When I'm developing locally, I set the Title of the app to be an abbreviation so I know which is which (local dev or published copy) when launching from the app menu.

I forgot to change the abbreviation back to the full name when published, but I thought that everything in the WMAppManifest.xml was overwritten with the metadata you enter in the app hub anyway.

Comment: What happened? The update now renamed your app to abbreviation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information you enter while submitting is for the marketplace. The Title to be displayed in the phone is extracted from your .xap. Thus, you may see the correct title in the marketplace but not on the device.
Also happened to me once :).

Comment: The marketplace also shows the abbreviated name too, not just the app.

Comment: Original Name: Checkbook Metro. Abbreviation: cbm. App on the phone and in the marketplace. Search for 'Checkbook Metro' in the marketplace search and you'll find no results.

Comment: They must have changed it.. the desired title of my app was VoltNote but in the .xap it was Notes. When I used to search for VoltNote, I used to see Notes in the market too (but it did show up).. but the apps like AppFlow showed it as VoltNote...
In anycase it really doesn't matter since you already know now what 'really' happens.. just submit an update :)

Comment: I had to post cause I thought I was crazy. Thanks for the verification :)